# map.set() returning a NaN unless I add double pipes?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, object, data-structures, hashtable

I’m having a hard time understanding why the “|| 1” makes this work.

Without the OR operator it returns NaN for every key.

[desired result - with “||”](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAub9.jpg)

[without “||” - results in NaN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ow7x3.jpg)

Comment: If the map *doesn't have* a given key, then `map.get(key)` returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to increase it at first you’re doing a `map.get()` with a key that doesn’t exist in the map. That results in `undefined`. Adding something to `undefined` isn’t sensible so it’s a `NaN`.

Your fix makes it put `1` there instead since `NaN` is falsy. Then the next time the same string is tried a value is in the map and it can be retrieved and one can be added to it.